# How to display Hindi numbers in SSRS?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reportviewer, hindi

In Arabic language we use Hindi Numbers (٠‎ -١‎ - ٢‎ - ٣‎ - ٤‎ - ٥‎ - ٦‎ - ٧‎ - ٨‎ - ٩‎) to represent (0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9)

The question is how to display numbers in SSRS reports using these Hindi figures?

Comment: Nothing to do at report level, you mush have column data type to nVarchar which containing Hindi

Answer (score 0):

You can't do any such thing at report level, store the data in database as Hindi number format in desired column of the table and then simply select that column to display data in SSRS report via query or stored procedure.

Answer (score -2):

In `Localization` section change `Language` property of a textbox to `ar-SA` and `NumeralVariant` to `3`.